Is it possible to make a texture map that controls where shadows appear? And can I use that same map to display stylized dynamic shadows?
I'm making a low poly character (think like a mixture between a psp character and a character model from final fantasy 8) that makes it difficult to display rendered shadows without it looking Jank as hell. So I wanted to know if I can make a special map that displays intentionally made shadows depending on the rotation of the camera? I also kind of wanted to make the character with a style similar to that of Sonic riders if you ever saw the opening for it, (with the cross hatching shadows and such, I'll post a link to the opening)https://youtu.be/3dYgTNOjsI8?si=g8V9jLxfRxX5_qtO

You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of asking users to visit links just to understand your question. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.sstatic.net/vHwEx.png) and use the tools on the site to upload images directly. See: How to upload an image to a post?.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
